# Using a ref Parameter with the this Keyword?

Tags: c#, ref, this-pointer

Is there a way to force the this keyword to act as a ref argument? I would like to pass in a visitor that modifies multiple properties on the object, but this only wants to act like a value parameter.

Code in Object:

```
public void Accept(Visitor<MyObject> visitor)
{
    visitor.Visit(this);
}
```

Code in Visitor:

```
public void Visit(ref Visitor<MyObject> receiver)
{
    receiver.Property = new PropertyValue();
    receiver.Property2 = new PropertyValue();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are not actually changing what `receiver` refers to there is no need for the `ref` keyword. However, if that would have been the case, you would not be able to make `this` refer to another instance.

In order to pass `this` as a `ref` parameter, you would need to write it like this:

```
Visit(ref this);
```

That code will not compile: *"Cannot pass '<this>' as a ref or out argument because it is read-only"*

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right. But I want the original class to retain the changes made by the Visitor. If I don't pass as ref, then won't I only modify the properties of a *copy* of <this>?

Comment: @grefly: Not if "this" is a class.  Provided you don't "visit" custom struct (value types), ref isn't required.

Answer (score 5):

If your `Visitor<T>` is a class, then you don't need the `ref` keyword.

All the info inside a class is automatically changed if they are changed in a method

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you got an answer to your larger question already. But let's consider this one anyway.

> Is there a way to force the this keyword to act as a ref argument?

Yes.  Work it through logically.

- A ref argument makes an *alias* for a *variable*.
- "this" is not a variable in a reference type
- "this" is a variable in a value type
- therefore the only way to pass a "ref this" is from an instance method of a value type.

And in fact that is how "this" is implemented in a value type behind the scenes. When you have a (worst practice! do not actually do this) mutable value type:

```
struct S
{
    private int x;
    public void M()
    {
        this.x = 123;
    }
}
...
S s = new S();
s.M();
```

Since instances of S are *passed by value* how is it that M mutates s?  s must be passed by reference!  In fact the code we generate is just as if you'd written something like:

```
struct S
{
    private int x;
    public static void M(ref S THIS)
    {
        THIS.x = 123;
    }
}
...
S s = new S();
S.M(ref s);
```

In short, a "this" in a struct already is passed as a ref parameter, so there is no problem passing it along again. Doing so is almost always a *terrible idea* but it is legal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the ref keyword ?

ref would be useful if you change receiver instance
e.g.
receiver = null;

otherwise

receiver.Property is accessible also without ref keyword